# Trying to make a film-grade rig for animated music videos

Tags: animation, rigging

I'm really trying to make a sturdy rig that deforms properly for a music video I have been wanting to make for over 3 years.  I have modeled and texture the rig, and I also have the face rig figured out, but the mesh deforming is giving me a really hard time.  I believe the topology is good... enough.
I have tried finding tutorials about it but I can't find anything I'm looking for.

Here is the model:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Are their any tutorials or anything that might help?
If not how could I achieve this?

Comment: Hello, "but the mesh deforming is giving me a really hard time" is a bit vague, could you please elaborate?